# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on presentViewController:animated:completion

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, jasidepanels

I have been trying to solve this for the past two days. Unable to understand why my app crashes.

I'm using `JASidePanel` library to achieve panel effect in my app. The left side panel is a tableview which acts like navigation guide for the centre panel. In one scenario, when a particular option is selected in the left side panel (when this is open), the centre panel is supposed to just close the left side panel and present another navigation controller (with a consistent) root view controller. However, sometimes this transition crashes my app.

I observed that the crash does not happen in the JASidePanel's code or my Centre panel View Controller code (`[self presentViewController:self.cityNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];`). I clearly observed that the app crashes due to some internal crash because of the iOS framework, I went through each instruction by instruction and figured this out.

But still, I think I'm doing something wrong. Can anyone suggest me why this crash could happen? What should I be looking for to resolve this issue? Any steps or procedures I can/should follow to detect the problem?

Any help is appreciated.

**Device Log:**

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a085b26 objc_msgSend + 6
1   UIKit                           0x3257c788 -[UISearchBar _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 152
2   UIKit                           0x3249a576 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 662
3   UIKit                           0x3249a576 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 662
4   UIKit                           0x324bb5e2 -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 46
5   UIKit                           0x3249a576 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 662
6   UIKit                           0x3249a576 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 662
7   UIKit                           0x3249a576 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 662
8   UIKit                           0x3249a576 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 662
9   UIKit                           0x32499e68 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 108
10  Foundation                      0x30688d98 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 208
11  UIKit                           0x32499cf2 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 294
12  UIKit                           0x324a6998 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1400
13  UIKit                           0x324a6412 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 26
14  UIKit                           0x32587d8a -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 974
15  UIKit                           0x32587998 -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:] + 444
16  UIKit                           0x32587406 __101-[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:]_block_invoke_2 + 1250
17  UIKit                           0x3251afb6 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 314
18  UIKit                           0x324931ee _afterCACommitHandler + 426
19  CoreFoundation                  0x2fcf31ca __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2fcf0b6c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 280
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2fcf0eae __CFRunLoopRun + 726
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2fc5bc22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
23  CoreFoundation                  0x2fc5ba06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
24  GraphicsServices                0x3493a27e GSEventRunModal + 134
25  UIKit                           0x324ff044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
26  Housing India                   0x000a2606 main (main.m:16)
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a592ab4 start + 0
```

Comment: Have you observed a device log?

Comment: I could not make out a lot from the device log. I edited my code. Have a look. If possible, explain me.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS means you are accessing an object which has been deallocated. Try to check your objects when you are presenting your controller.

Comment: I have a strong pointer pointing at the navigation controller. The object is not `nil`. I have checked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, If for any one this helps.

The problem was with the iOS Framework. The problem was with UINavigationController's implementation. The crash was happening inside the framework itself. The only possible way out was to instantiate the Navigation Controller every time, before presenting it. This decreases performance, but had no other option. Apple, really does have a lot of limitations and assumptions. :P

**Explanation:** We needed to present a Navigation Controller with Modal animation. We were trying to avoid the instantiation of the navigation controller again and again by instantiating it once and trying to reuse it. However, because of this, we observed a crash happening sometime. Don't exactly know what the crash means, but fixed it by instantiating it again and again.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate a little more on what the problem was and how did you solve it? what do you mean by "The only possible way out was to instantiate the Navigation Controller every time, before presenting it."

Comment: @ManicMonkOnMac: I tried to explain. Let me know if you understand it.